# How to switch or change user in Hue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

Is there an option to switch user in HUE?

In my organization, infrastructure team setup usecase id, which has all HDFS file system access and only usecase id can submit yarn jobs. Individual user can sudo 
 to usecase id `sudo su - xyz`. There are no password for usecase id.

I am able to login to HUE but can't submit any jobs as I don't have access to any queue so I want to switch to usecase id, after login to HUE. How to switch user ( `sudo su - xyz`) in hue?

Answer (score 2):

Hue, by default,  can only run under the first account that's logged in with.

You need to ask the infrastructure team to configure Hue with a PAM or LDAP login authentication, in which case the password will be required for any Hue login user

Once that's setup, you are also able to switch accounts.

There are other configurations, but for enterprise users, I think those are the best options other than some single sign on OAuth/OpenID tool.

---

There's also SPNEGO, and that'll require a completely kerberized cluster.

Realistically, your company sounds like their cluster is not using Kerberos, so it isn't even secure.

For example, don't even need to sudo... Just export a variable

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=usecase
```

Of course, this isn't possible in Hue, but if you already have SSH access, you really can do anything in the cluster you want to

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my organisation, single sign on is enabled using Okta (like LDAP), and same is used to login to bigdata cluster. We are using Mapr hadoop distribution which uses native mapr authentication and Kerberos KDC for security and governance.

Comment: Yeah, my client is currently using OKTA as well, however, I don't actually know how to integrate Hue into it.

Answer (score 0):

Configure yarn core-site.xml to impersonate hue users to access yarn cluster for submitting jobs.

1. key: **hadoop.proxyuser.default_user.hosts**

value: *

2. key: **hadoop.proxyuser.default_user.groups**

value: *

Replace **default_user** with **hue** or any system user manages your application.

Hue supports different backend module for authentication and authorization.

- django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend
- desktop.auth.backend.AllowAllBackend
- desktop.auth.backend.AllowFirstUserDjangoBackend
- desktop.auth.backend.LdapBackend
- desktop.auth.backend.PamBackend
- desktop.auth.backend.SpnegoDjangoBackend
- desktop.auth.backend.RemoteUserDjangoBackend
- libsaml.backend.SAML2Backend
- libopenid.backend.OpenIDBackend
- liboauth.backend.OAuthBackend (New oauth, support Twitter, Facebook, Google+ and Linkedin)

Each module has its own advantage and disadvantages. For a very large scale deployment where multiple user need to access HUE application, LDAP, SAML2, Oauth authentication is preferred over PAM and Django based login.

Comment: Thanks. My enterprises uses Mapr Hadoop distribution and I am not allowed to updated the cluster config files (like yarn-site.xml). Hue authentication is enabled using singlesignon OKTA with LDAP.